# Run time environment for Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-plugins

I am building a hadoop pig editor, similar like sql editor where user can write execute their pig command, and view history of commands executed.There is intelligence as well.

I need to know how do i parse my pig command and run it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you already have one? Grunt shell? http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/setup.html#Grunt+Shell

Comment: You can go for Talend open Studio